# Cannot get texture to render using UV map

Tags: modeling, texturing, uv

I'm new to Blender and am trying to understand UV mapping using this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XeBUfMKKZDo

I modeled a simple staircase by starting with a cube. First I subdivided two adjacent edges, then I added new edges to connect the new vertices, and finally I moved the new vertices to form a staircase. Propably not the most efficient way to do the job, but I wanted to do something simple that (I think) I understand.

Then I followed the tutorial and added seams to my model and made an UV unwrap to it. The unwrap looks exactly as it should in the UV editor, but when I continued to add an UV grid texture to the model like in the tutorial, the resulting texture is a complete mess.

[image]

I've tried to do the UV unwrap several times with little changes, but it doesn't affect the result. My best guess is that the UV map is correct, but for some reason it is not used in the model and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Edit. I appended the model to a clean project, but it still behaves the same. Here is link to the file. [image]

Comment: Can you add a screen shot showing your material?

Comment: Hi! Could you please share your blend file  https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: Have you accidentally created and edited another UV map? https://i.stack.imgur.com/LLqUE.jpg The selected UV map is the one you see in the editor on the left side. The one with the camera icon is the one you see in the viewport on the right side.

Comment: I added a blend file with the problem.

Comment: It's exactly what I've asked you in my previous comment. Maybe you missed it. You have 2 UV maps. Select the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. In fact I did check that, but somehow didn't understand that automap was the second one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated by Blunder you have 2 UV maps. Removing the unused UV and unwrapping the one named "automap" solved the issue.

[image: removing unnecessary UV Map]

Also you do not need that many seams for a staircase. I've attached an example below, this will help save performance during renders, although your method might allow for a specific texturing workflow.

[image: cleaning up seams]